# Loki JS doesn't persist data in Ionic

Tags: database, cordova, ionic-framework, lokijs

I'm using LokiJS to save in local storage (well, I'm trying) .
What I want to do is a ToDo app, my controller is as follows:

```
.controller('Dash', function($scope) {

    var db = new loki('loki.json');
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.lname="";

    var users=db.getCollection('users');

    if (users==null) {
      $scope.message="It's null";
      var users = db.addCollection('users');
    }else{
      $scope.message="It's ready";
    }

    $scope.insert=function(namesI, lnameI){
      users.insert({
        name: namesI,
        lname:lnameI
       }); 

   }
```

The issue is that everytime that I test it, the message is "It's null". Although before already I have inserted data. I mean, everytime I launch the app, the database is created.

How I can persist the data?
*I'm not using any cordova plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a `loadHandler` function, so you are trying to access collections before Loki is finished loading the json file. Look at this [example](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/wiki/LokiJS-persistence-and-adapters#autosave-with-autoload-example) for a clarification on how to use the autoLoadHandler.

Also bear in mind that at some stage you need to call `db.saveDatabase()` to persist, or else you need to provide an `autoSaveInterval` value when instantiating Loki.